# Add custom paging in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I've used paging of gridview .But in one of my project i want to add paging like
 Previous 1 2 3.. Next
Is there any way by which I can do the same

I know numeric and previous next but it is combination of both

Answer (score 2):

This will require manual coding as there is NO inbuilt functionality as of today to get the Pager as:  `Previous 1 2 3.. Next`

With the Courtesy of **[BLEERMAKERS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18973/Implementing-a-NextPrev-Numeric-Pager-in-ASP-NET)** , One very great way that fascinated me was to create a custom control to achieve this. Posting here the basic code to get started.

```
public class CustomGridView : GridView
{
CustomGridView grd;
protected void PrevNextClick(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "PREV") {grd.PageIndex += -1;}
else { grd.PageIndex += 1;}
GridViewPageEventArgs gvpea = new GridViewPageEventArgs(grd.PageIndex);
grd.OnPageIndexChanging(gvpea);
}

protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
base.OnRowCreated(e);
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
{

Table pagerTable = (Table)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
grd = this;
TableRow pagerRow = pagerTable.Rows[0];
PagerSettings pagerSettings = grd.PagerSettings;
int cellsCount = pagerRow.Cells.Count;

if (pagerSettings.Mode == PagerButtons.Numeric || pagerSettings.Mode == PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast)
{
//check whether previous button exists
LinkButton btnPrev = new LinkButton();
btnPrev.Text = pagerSettings.PreviousPageText;
btnPrev.CommandName = "PREV";
if (grd.PageIndex <= 0) btnPrev.Visible = false;
btnPrev.Command += PrevNextClick;
TableCell PrevCell = new TableCell();

PrevCell.Controls.Add(btnPrev);
pagerRow.Cells.AddAt(0, PrevCell);

//check whether previous button exists
LinkButton btnNext = new LinkButton();
btnNext.Text = pagerSettings.NextPageText;
btnNext.CommandName = "NEXT";
if (grd.PageIndex >= grd.PageCount - 1) btnNext.Visible = false;
btnNext.Command += PrevNextClick;
TableCell NextCell = new TableCell();
NextCell.Controls.Add(btnNext);
pagerRow.Cells.Add(NextCell);
}
}
}
}
```

Add this to your web.config (assuming the above code is in app_code, you can also use an assembled version):

```
<system.web>
<pages>
<controls>
<add namespace="CustomControls" tagPrefix="CC" />
</controls>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

To use a CustomGridView in a .aspx file:

```
<CC:CustomGridView ID="CustomGridView1"
runat="server"
AllowPaging="True"
DataSourceID="DataSource1"
PageSize="10"
PagerSettings-NextPageText="Next page"
PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="Previous page"
PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast"
/>
```

[Read on here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18973/Implementing-a-NextPrev-Numeric-Pager-in-ASP-NET) to get a complete Idea.